# Error: unknown type name

Tags: c

El error daría en la utilización como parámetro en los dos métodos de personaje.h que utilizan el Tipo Bandera , diciendo que no conoce ese tipo.

```
    #ifndef __PERSONAJE_H
    #define __PERSONAJE_H
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include "Bandera.h"
    #include "ListaPLataformas.h"
    #include "plataforma.h"
    #include "Pantalla.h"


    typedef struct PersonajeRep * Personaje;


    Personaje crea_Personaje(double x, double y,int vy,int vx );

    int actualiza_Personaje(Personaje p,ListaPlataformas l,int x_c,Bandera b,time_t* fin);
    ....
    int colisision_Bandera(Personaje p,Bandera b);

    ....


   #endif
```

Este es el .h que me crea el conflicto de unknown type name "Bandera".
La cosa es que yo antes tenia una referencia cíclica con la inclusión de los encabezados, y moví ya el unico método que me hacia que incluyera el personaje.h en Bandera.h , ese método era colision_Bandera(Personaje p,Bandera b).

Así que ya no se porque da este error y no consigo arreglarlo.

Aqui estaria el codigo de Bandera.h.

```
  #ifndef __BANDERA_H
  #define __BANDERA_H

  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include "Pantalla.h"


  typedef struct BanderaRep * Bandera;

  Bandera crea_Bandera(double x, double y);


   void dibujar_Bandera(Bandera b);

   void transforma_Bandera(int x_c,Bandera b);

   double getAncho_Bandera(Bandera b);
   double getAlto_Bandera(Bandera b);
   double getX_Bandera(Bandera b);
   double getY_Bandera(Bandera b);

   void libera_Bandera(Bandera b);

   #endif
```

Muchísimas  gracias por adelantado a quien pueda ayudarme con este error.

**EDI1:**

Aqui estataria la informacion de compilador. O es otra cosa la que necesitas?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct PersonajeRep * Personaje;
```

Para poder definir el alias `Personaje` debe estar declarado previamente una estructura de nombre `PersonajeRep`:

```
struct PersonajeRep
{
  // ...
};

typedef struct PersonajeRep* Personaje;
```

O al menos deberías usar *declaration forward*:

```
struct PersonajeRep;

typedef struct PersonajeRep* Personaje;

// ...

struct PersonajeRep
{
  // ...
};
```

Y lo mismo para `Bandera`. Si esas estructuras ya las tienes definidas lo que te falta es añadir el `#include` correspondiente para que el compilador pueda conocer la estructura.